# Boost.Python and Python exceptions

Tags: c++, boost-python

How can I make boost.python code python exceptions aware?

For example,

```
int test_for(){
  for(;;){
  }
  return 0;
}
```

doesn't interrupt on Ctrl-C, if I export it to python. I think other exceptions 
won't work this way to.

This is a toy example. My real problem is that I have a C function that may take hours to compute. And I want to interrupt it, if it takes more that hour for example. But I don't want to kill python instance, within the function was called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this. A simple and complete working example would be most helpful, if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C or C++ code, install a signal handler for SIGINT that sets a global flag and have your long-running function check that flag periodically and return early when the flag is set. Alternatively, instead of an early return, you can raise a Python exception using the Python C API: see PyErr_SetInterrupt [here](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/api/exceptionHandling.html).

Comment: The proper way to do this under Boost.Python is not to use the C API directly, but install an exception translator:

register_exception_translator<RuntimeException>(my_runtime_exception_translator);

void
my_runtime_exception_translator(RuntimeException const& ex)
{
   PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, ex.toString().c_str());
}

Comment: Exception translators translate C++ exceptions to Python exceptions. I think the poster here wants the opposite: expose the KeyboardInterrupt python exception to C++.

Comment: I'm interested in this answer too. A minimal working example would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure boost.python has a solution - you may have to deal with this by yourself. In which case it is no different than conventional signal handling. The easy solution is to have a global variable which is changed by the signal handler, and to [check this variable regularly](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Defining-Handlers.html#Defining-Handlers). The other solution is to use setjmp/longjmp, but I think the first way is best when applicable, because it is simple and much more maintainable.

Note that this is unix specific - I don't know how this works on windows.